# Turtle to walk along a predefined list of GPS coordinates in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I have created a turtle in netlogo from a shapefile containing it's coordinates, I want the turtle to walk along a predefined list of GPS coordinates which is currently saved as a csv file with three attributes (ID, X,Y) where X and Y are the coordinates, ID contains sequential numbers from 1 to 5000. Thanks

Comment: What's the question? Please be specific rather than ask for someone to do a project for you.

Comment: If you break it down into parts you can probably trick us into doing it for you.

Comment: oloo: Example: Focus on the coordinates.  That they are GPS coordinates doesn't matter.  Investigate: How do I move a turtle to one pair of coordinates?  (Then do the same thing for other small pieces of your project.)

Comment: thanks everyone, i got some help from the work of these authors "Host, S. T. S. M., and Hans Skov-Petersen. "EXPLORING AGENT-BASED MODELLING TECHNIQUE FOR CYCLE TRACK MODELLING." ...there are links to netlogo files within the report